# Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Does exist an example of a Galois extension $L/K$ such that $\text{Gal}(L/K)\cong \mathbb Z$?

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, there is no such extension.

Comment: Might as well move this to an answer, even though it's only one sentence.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871485

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Galois group of a field extension $L/K$ is profinite, which $\mathbb{Z}$ is not.